# How to configure Nats supercluster to publish messages across two super-clusters running with different operators via gateways

Tags: nats.io, runatserver

Can we form Nats supercluster with 2 or more clusters operates with different operators if we configure with nsc? if so how can we send a message from one cluster to another through gateway.

We tried at our end, but it didnt work. We also gave permissions one account to another account which are in different operators. We are using Service only not using streams.
But we are getting below errror:

```
can't locate account [xyz] for import of [testsubject]
```